# Access Contents In An Iframe jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea in an iframe. When I try to do any type of jquery manipulation in the textarea it will not respond.

The text area initially loads data in the iframe fine with this simple code..

```
//txtHozSliderEmail is the textarea in the iframe
 $('#txtHozSliderEmail').val(notificationTemplate.Body)
```

but when I change the value of notificationTemplate.Body on subsequent calls, the data from the first call displays. The textarea wont update. I verified that notificationTemplate.Body has different data in it on every call so its not that.

The iframe is nested inside the main page.

When I check the "frames" collection I can see it has 2 frames how can I see the names of them? It seems the iframe has no id when I look at it in the html. Do I have to give it an "id" to access it or some other attribute?

The iframe is on the same domain/server I am not accessing an outside domain. The iframe is being used in the jHtmlArea.js library

Here the code in the library that is creating the iframe:

```
  var iframe = this.iframe = $("<iframe/>").height(textarea.height());
        iframe.width('580px');
        iframe.height('180px');
        //iframe.width(textarea.width() - ($.browser.msie ? 0 : 4));
        var htmlarea = this.htmlarea = $("<div/>").append(iframe);
```

Comment: need more detail about code. Are you trying to run code from page inside iFrame or from main page? They are 2 different documents so it is important to clarify

Comment: the iframe is nested inside the main page

Comment: well of course iFrame is in page... doesn't explain where code resides

Comment: This question should give you what you need: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/364997/1220302

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: The iframe doesnt have an "id" do I have to add an "id" or some other attribute to access it?